# A question about splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting field of $x^{n}-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24056/splitting-field-of-xn-1-over-mathbbq)

Let $A$ denote the splitting field of $x^n-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, so what is the dimension of $A$ as a linear space over $\mathbb{Q}$? (in this question, $n$ is a positive integer)

Comment: It is $\Phi(n)$ where $\Phi$ is the Euler $\Phi$-function.

Comment: See this previous question: [Splitting field of $x^n-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$][1]


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24056/splitting-field-of-xn-1-over-mathbbq

Answer (score 5):

The degree is $\varphi(n)$, where $\varphi$ is the [Euler phi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Note that if $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, then we have a map
$$
\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbf Q(\zeta)/\mathbf Q) \to (\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^*
$$
sending $\sigma$ to the class of an integer $i$ for which $\sigma(\zeta) = \zeta^i$. You can check that this is well-defined and injective — the hard part is showing surjectivity. The usual way of doing this is to show that the $n$-th [cyclotomic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) is irreducible by reducing it mod $p$ and exploiting the [Frobenius automorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism). You can see a proof in, for example, Keith Conrad's [notes on cyclotomic fields](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf).