# Counting endomorphisms of $\mathbf Q(\zeta _{n})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory

If $\zeta= \zeta_{n}$, how does one count the homomorphisms $f:\mathbf{Q}(\zeta)\rightarrow \mathbf{Q}(\zeta)$?

Comment: Where can $\zeta$ go to?

Comment: I don't think it would hurt to say what $\zeta_n$ is and what your thoughts are so far. This is more or less the same as [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24056/splitting-field-of-xn-1-over-mathbbq) modulo some field theory, which I'll try to explain.

Answer (score 4):

Let $k = \mathbf Q(\zeta)$. Since it is the splitting field of $X^n - 1$, $k$ is [Galois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension) over $\mathbf Q$. Homomorphisms of rings should respect $1$, which implies that $f$ is injective and restricts to the identity on $\mathbf Q$.  By looking at dimensions over $\mathbf Q$, it is also surjective. So finding the number of $f$ is the same as determining
\[
\#\operatorname{Gal}(k/\mathbf Q) = [k : \mathbf Q] = \text{degree of the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$}.
\]
There's a sketch of and reference to a proof that this number is $\varphi(n)$ [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64215/a-question-about-splitting-field/64217#64217).