# Find the splitting field of $x^3-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

> Find the splitting field of $x^3-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

My try:

Factoring this to the most I can (in $\mathbb{Q}$), we get that $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

So $x=1$ is a root of $f(x)$.

$x^2+x+1$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$ so I conclude it is irreducible (since we have a low degree of $2$)

Can I conclude that the splitting field of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(1)=\mathbb{Q}$ because $1\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Or do I have to keep factoring, assuming that the roots I find will be in some extension field?

Like:

$x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ gives the roots $x=1, x=\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}, x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$, in which case the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(1,\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2},\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2})$. But if this is the case, I'm not sure how to simplify this.

Comment: Does the polynomial $f$ factor into linear factors over $\mathbb{Q}$? If not, then this is not the splitting field.

Comment: See the answer  [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24056/splitting-field-of-xn-1-over-mathbbq).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convince yourself, by using the quadratic formula to solve:

$x^2 + x + 1 = 0$

that the splitting field of $x^3 - 1$ is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$.

Note: it is customary to denote this field as $\Bbb Q(\omega)$, where:

$\omega = -\dfrac{1}{2} + i\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Therefore, convince yourself that $\Bbb Q(\omega) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$.

It may be helpful to recall the formula for the *discriminant* of a quadratic equation.

Comment: :It should be $\sqrt {-1}$ in place of  $\sqrt {-3}$ in your answer.

Comment: No, it should not. $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-1}) = \Bbb Q(i)$ is the rational complex numbers, and does not even contain a square root of $3$. However, $\omega$, as posted in my answer, is clearly in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$ as: $\omega = \frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{-3}-1)$

Comment: :Apologies,i misunderstood your answer.But,now i got it.Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

The splitting field of $x^3 - 1$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb Q$ and all of its roots in $\mathbb{C}$ i.e. $$\mathbb{Q} \left(1, \frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}, \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right) = \mathbb{Q} \left(\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}, \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)$$
Of course if you want you can always write it as a simple extension of $\mathbb Q$ (using the [primitive element theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem))