# Find the splitting field of $x^3-1$ over $\mathbb Q$. Express your answer in the form $\mathbb Q(a).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Find the splitting field of $x^3-1$ over $\mathbb Q$. Express your answer in the form $\mathbb Q(a).$

Solution: Let $\mathbb E$ be a splitting field for $x^3-1$ over $\mathbb Q$. Then $x^3-1$ can be factored as a product of linear factors in  $\mathbb E[x]$.
$$x^3-1=(x-1)(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)$$
where $\omega $ is the third root of unity.

We also know that splitting field of $f(x)$ (*nonconstant*) over a field $\mathbb F$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb F$ and all of its roots.

Thus $\mathbb E=\mathbb Q(1,\omega,\omega^2)$.

**Is it correct?**

Need help in representing the splitting field in the form $\mathbb Q(a)$.

Also please explain the answer by David Wheeler in [Find the splitting field of $x^3-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207964/find-the-splitting-field-of-x3-1-over-mathbbq)

Comment: You have the correct field, but it's not expressed in the required form $\mathbb{Q}(a)$. However, since $1 \in \mathbb{Q}$, you don't need to adjoin $1$, and since $\omega^2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$, you don't need to adjoin $\omega^2$. Thus, you can express $E$ as just $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$.

Comment: About the last sentence of your question: since $2\omega=-1+\sqrt{-3}$, we have $\mathbb Q(\omega)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$.

Comment: thanks a lot.You made my day@quasi &@Pierre-Yves Gaillard

Comment: I removed the tag [tag:finite-fields]. Last time I checked $\Bbb{Q}$ had infinitely many elements :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's correct, and $$\mathbb Q(1,\omega ,\omega ^2)=\mathbb Q(\omega )=\{a+b\omega +c\omega ^2\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb Q\}.$$